# Cannot locate the Visual Recognition Module on Watson Studio Lite

Tags: watson-studio

I am following a tutorial that requires me to select the visual recognition module as the next step of selecting create a project.

However, after clicking create project, I only see two options:

- Create an empty project
- Create a project from a sample or file

Could you please let me know how to access the visual recognition module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the new design changes, you can create a new empty project.
[image]

[image]

Once the project is created, Click Add to Project Button.
[image]

Select Image Classification Model (for creating VR Classification Model).
[image]

You would need to select or provision a new VR service to use for training your model.
[image]

Once you do that you are ready to upload image files and start the classification and training.
[image]